# import data into sql server using SSIS

Tags: ssis

how to import data from sql server on basis of excel sheet and some master tables in ssis

Answer (score 0):

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=205

sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic637794-148-1.aspx

Search around Google - there's plenty out there.